# React Native CLI, Cannot find module '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-native-cli/node_modules/prompt/lib/prompt'

Tags: node.js, react-native

I'm having a problem installing the react native CLI

When I run `react-native init` or any other cli method

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:296
      throw err;
      ^

Error: Cannot find module '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-native-cli/node_modules/prompt/lib/prompt'. Please verify that the package.json has a valid "main" entry
    at tryPackage (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:288:19)
    at Function.Module._findPath (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:515:18)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:759:27)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:677:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:830:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:68:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-native-cli/index.js:43:14)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:936:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:947:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:32) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-native-cli/node_modules/prompt/package.json',
  requestPath: 'prompt'
}
```

Removed and re-installed using `npm install -g react-native-cli` but no luck.

node version v12.10.0,
npm version 6.10.3

Answer (score 0):

This was resolved by completely removing Node and re-installing using homebrew

Answer (score 0):

I was resolved by removing `node` and remove this folder  `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-native-cli/node_modules/` and reinstall `node`

Answer (score 0):

run command (yarn add npm) if you have yarn
I have resolved my issue with this command

Answer (score 0):

fixed it by deleting 'npm' folder at C:\Users\**your_user_name**\AppData\Roaming\npm and then `npx react-native init AwesomeProjectName`